# Compley MySQL SELECT to get distinct value with connected times

Tags: mysql, select, join, distinct

I have this fiddle right here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/863fe3

I need to select, for example, "Times Square" (as a project or place) with the sum of the time the people (in this case Mr. Anderson & Mr. Winkler) were there and the sum based on each person too.

I really have no idea how to get these different sums related to the place/project.

Hope you can help me with that.

The output should be:

```
Project Time Square | total 12:59:00
        Winkler     | total on Time Square 7:45:00
        Anderson    | total on Time Square 3:45:00
```

Comment: What are you summing? What would the desired result look like? Also, use a proper DATETIME data type for dates.

Comment: Project: Times Square | total: XX:XX:XX | Winkler total: XX:XX:XX at, Anderson total: XX:XX:XX

Comment: There's an `edit` button at the bottom of your question